# Logarithmic functions complex

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Are logarithmic functions not defined for negative real numbers?

Since either part of a complex number (real and imaginary) can be 0 then isn't the above statement false and hence they are defined for negative real numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $e^z$ is periodic with period $2\pi i$, $\log z$ assumes countably infinitely many distinct values for each nonzero $z\in \mathbb C$, each differing by an integral multiple of $2\pi i$.

$\log 0$ does not exist because there is no complex $w$ such that $e^w=0$.

For your particular question, if $x>0$, then the values of $\log (-x)$ are
$$\ell_k = \ln x + (2k+1)\pi i$$
for integral $k$, where $\ln$ is the familiar real-valued function of a positive real variable. Note that none of these are real numbers since the imaginary part is always nonzero (an odd multiple of $\pi$). The "simplest" is $\ln x + \pi i$.

---

**Note:** A similar ambiguity actually exists for *positive* reals as well: if $x>0$, then the values of $\log x$ are
$$\ell_k = \ln x + 2k\pi i$$ for integral $k$, where $\ln$ is the familiar real-valued function of a positive real variable. Of course, you usually only think about this simplest case by assuming $k=0$ and you have the value $\ln x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So then the above statement is true?

Comment: To what statement do you refer? I see only questions, not statements ;-) The difficulty is that the logarithm can be defined for negative reals, but it is not real-valued. In addition, you have to choose which of the infinitely many values to select (for example, you may want to specify that the imaginary part of $\log z$ must lie in $(-\pi,\pi]$, or in $[0,2\pi)$, etc) to make it an honest-to-goodness function (single-valued). The logarithm then **can be defined for negative reals**.